# Printar um atributo de varias classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos

Estou criando um programa que irá lançar os produtos de estabelecimentoe e criando cada produto sendo um objeto ja que eles possuem tipo, nome e preço. Quero imprimir um atriburo especifico de cada objeto através de um loop, por exemplo, todos os preços em uma lista. Seria possível?
Outra coisa, vocês acham que essa é a melhor forma de separar os produtos? Ou deveria apenas criar alguns vetores?

Segue o meu código:

```
class Produtos:
    def __init__(self, tipo, nome, preco):
        self.tipo = tipo
        self.nome = nome
        self.preco = preco

    def produto(self):
        print(self.tipo)
        print(self.nome)
        print(self.preco)


expresso = Produtos("Café", "Expresso", 4.9)
cf_com_leite_medio = Produtos("Café", "Café com leite Médio", 5.7)
cf_com_chantilly = Produtos("Café", "Café com Chantilly", 8)
cf_duplo = Produtos("Café", "Café Duplo", 8.5)
cf_com_cointreau = Produtos("Café", "Café com Cointreau", 8.5)
cf_italiano = Produtos("Café", "Café Italiano", 8.5)
cpp_pequeno = Produtos("Café", "Cappuccino pequeno", 5.5)
cpp_grande = Produtos("Café", "Cappuccino grande", 8)
cpp_gelado = Produtos("Café", "Cappuccino Gelado", 14.5)
latte_macchiatto = Produtos("Café", "Latte Macchiatto", 7)

print(cf_com_leite_medio.tipo)
print(cf_com_chantilly.tipo)
```

Comment: Um detalhe não relacionado ao problema: se a classe representa um único produto, o nome deveria ser `Produto` (no singular). Ao chamá-la de `Produtos` (no plural), isso dá a entender que ela representa vários produtos, o que não é verdade. Pode parecer um detalhe bobo, mas [dar nomes melhores ajuda muito na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad) :-)

Comment: Muito bom! Obrigado pela dica

Answer (score 1):

Basta colocar todos os seus objetos dentro de uma lista e percorrer dentro de uma estrutura de repetição `for`, dessa forma:

```
expresso = Produtos("Café", "Expresso", 4.9)
cf_com_leite_medio = Produtos("Café", "Café com leite Médio", 5.7)
cf_com_chantilly = Produtos("Café", "Café com Chantilly", 8)

for produto in [expresso, cf_com_leite_medio, cf_com_chantilly]:
    print(produto.tipo)
```

Para facilitar o processo, ao invés de criar uma variável para cada objeto, acrescente a uma lista já criada cada um de seus objetos. Exemplo:

```
produtos.append(Produtos("Café", "Expresso", 4.9))
produtos.append(Produtos("Café", "Café com leite Médio", 5.7))
produtos.append(Produtos("Café", "Café com Chantilly", 8))

for produto in produtos:
    print(produto.tipo)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 1):

Criar uma variável para cada produto, pode tornar o seu código muito extenso, de difícil compreensão e manutenção.

A utilização de uma lista cabe muito bem nesse seu exemplo, inclusive para efetuar então a iteração nos produtos, seja para exibir algum propriedade, somar o total dos preços etc.

---

Veja, criamos uma lista e cada instância da classe Produtos fica em uma posição da lista, dessa forma iterar e exibir a propriedade tipo fica muito mais simples:

```
class Produtos:
    def __init__(self, tipo, nome, preco):
        self.tipo = tipo
        self.nome = nome
        self.preco = preco

    def produto(self):
        print(self.tipo)
        print(self.nome)
        print(self.preco)

produtos = []

produtos.append( Produtos("Café", "Expresso", 4.9) )
produtos.append( Produtos("Café", "Café com leite Médio", 5.7) )
produtos.append( Produtos("Café", "Café com Chantilly", 8) )
produtos.append( Produtos("Café", "Café Duplo", 8.5) )
produtos.append( Produtos("Café", "Café com Cointreau", 8.5) )
produtos.append( Produtos("Café", "Café Italiano", 8.5) )
produtos.append( Produtos("Café", "Cappuccino pequeno", 5.5) )
produtos.append( Produtos("Café", "Cappuccino grande", 8) )
produtos.append( Produtos("Café", "Cappuccino Gelado", 14.5) )
produtos.append( Produtos("Café", "Latte Macchiatto", 7) )

for produto in produtos:
  print(produto.tipo)
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/ForkedFrozenAutotote

Comment: Muito melhor mesmo, implementarei a lista em meu código. Muito obrigado pela dica